# Empty div gets imaginary border in iPad/iPhone (Safari) browser

Tags: iphone, css, ipad, html

I have a page containing an empty div with a gradient in it, like this:

```
<div class="prodGradientArea"></div>

.prodGradientArea {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom , #ECEAE9 0%, #E4E3E2 50%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 10px;
    width: 420px;
}
```

This looks brilliant in FF, IE, Chrome and Safari ... on a computer. When checked in Safari on an iPad or iPhone, I get a tiny border around the div. This is removed if I write text in the box or if I zoom in a lot but not if I write a non-breaking white space. I have even tried putting in a transparent pixel with  but it made no difference to the imaginary border. Also tried setting border=0 but this was of course not the problem (it is not a real border, just a visual "feature").

So the only thing that removes it is to add pure text. I guess I can add a dot and hide it with color or so but it would break my little heart to make such an ugly fix.

Please help!

Jenny

Comment: I don't think you've included enough code. For example, that CSS only includes `-moz-linear-gradient`, where is the WebKit variant? A [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of the problem would be useful.

Comment: Could be outline? Try setting outline: 0; in your CSS. I'm not saying this is an answer, since I've never worked with iPads but it may be at a default value of 1px perhaps? Worth a shot I guess!

Answer (score 3):

Insert in your index.php this code in the `<head>`-area to avoid artifacts from bad zoom interpretation of iOS:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Then go to your css-file and insert a 1px negative margin, to avoid this. In my website this was the footer div:

```
.unten {
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

I hope this will help you, too!